# What could be causing running .eval() on a tensor to never end?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently going through [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn) tutorial on how to use TensorFlow to train a CNN and use it to categorize images based on the CIFAR-10 data set. When running the evaluation script, cifar10_eval.py, the output is a precision rating of how accurate the model is against the test set. I instead wanted to see the output of the model's classifications for each category on the test data. The way the logits are calculated and stored is through:

```
# Build a graph that computes the logits predictions from the 
# inference model. 
logits = cifar10.inference(images)
```

After running this line, I edited the script to display the type of the "logits" variable, its shape, and the type of its elements through the following:

```
print(type(logits))
print(logits.dtype)
print(logits.shape)
```

Which returns the following output:

> class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'
>
> dtype: 'float32'
>
> (128, 10)

I am assuming the shape is (128,10) for there being 128 test images with each image being given an evaluation on how likely it is to be each of the 10 categories. In order to display this I am trying the following code:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(logits.eval())
```

This .eval() statement never terminates, I was wondering where I've gone wrong and how to fix this so that I can access the logits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because you are opening a new session (and reinitializing the variables with that!). Try evaluating `logits` in the same session it is created. But it's weird that it doesn't terminate, it should raise an error. Also, it's `tf.Session()` not `tf.Session`

Comment: It isn't created within a tf.Session() block of code and adding one in where it is created gave me the same issue of not terminating. Fixed the typo in the code above.

Comment: i just looked at the code, and there is a tf.Session in the code, although it is a little hidden. The session is in `eval_once`. What you could do if you want to evaluate the logits, is to add a parameter `logits` to `eval_once`: `def eval_once(saver, summary_writer, top_k_op, summary_op, logits)` and then add the line `logits.eval()` after the line `predictions = sess.run([top_k_op])`